# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with NSRegularExpression matchesInString:

Tags: ios, regex, exc-bad-access

I have a line of code in my app that uses a regular expression to find PGP Keys in a string of user input.

```
    NSArray *pgpKeyMatch = [pgpKeyRegex matchesInString:userInput
                                                options:0
                                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, [userInput length])];
```

For most cases it works as expected. But I've run into a problem when a particularly long key is input (length of 334,629 instead of ~9,000). I get: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(CODE=1, ADDRESS=0X8)` and the app crashes.

I've tried using the Zombies instrument (which found nothing) and setting an Exception Breakpoint (which didn't yield any more information).

Stepping through the code shows that the NSRange is created successfully, but something goes wrong later in the execution of matchesInString: .

Does anyone have insight on what's causing this bad access? or why this is an issue only with this very long key? Below is a more complete excerpt of code:

```
NSString *userInput = self.inputKey.text;

NSError *pgpKeyRegexError = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *pgpKeyRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?:-----BEGIN PGP (?:PUBLIC|PRIVATE) KEY BLOCK-----)\n(?:(?:.*:.*)\n)*\n(?:[^-]|\n)*\n(?:-----END PGP (?:PUBLIC|PRIVATE) KEY BLOCK-----)"
                                                                             options:0
                                                                               error:&pgpKeyRegexError];



NSArray *pgpKeyMatch = [pgpKeyRegex matchesInString:userInput
                                            options:0
                                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [userInput length])];
```

Comment: are you checking if userInput is actually a valid pointer? Bad-access happens when trying to access bad memory, so your pointer might be NULL or something?

Comment: or if pgpKeyRegex was successfully created.

Comment: Yes, both point to valid objects. userInput points to the correct string and pgpKeyRegex has the correct pattern, options, and pgpRegexError is nil.

Comment: I found a work around where I just search for the beginning and end tags of a PGP key and combine the matched ranges instead of searching for the entire body of a key. For anyone else having a similar problem, it seems that something goes wrong in the matchesInString: method when the match will include such a large range of the string.